# How to detect the Language set in the Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to detect the language of the phone so that I can display the message accordingly. If it is english , then display english. Say, I target a few countries such as China,japan, Korea. How do I do it? here my incomplete code to show what I mean:

```
tring StrLanSetOnClient;

  string strLanEng= "english Msg";
  string strLanChn=" Msg in chinese character";
  string strLanJpn= "Msg in Japanese character";
  string strLanKor= "Msg in Korean character" ;


   strLanSetOnClient =  CultureInfo..........


 If( strLanSetOnClient == "English") 
  {
         txtBlkLan.Text = strLanEng;
  }
 elseif ( strLanSetOnClient == "Chinese")
 {
         txtBlkLan.Text = strLanChn
 }
....
```

Thanks
--- Updated Questions:

1) Where should I detect the language?  In App.xaml?
2) How all pages can refer to this global variable name?
3) Which is the best practise to detect ? use CultureInfo  or thread.currentThread

Thanks

```
&#lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&#gt;
&#lt;Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"&#gt;
  &#lt;ProjectExtensions&#gt;
    &#lt;VisualStudio &#gt;
      &#lt;FlavorProperties GUID="{C089C8C0-30E0-4E22-80C0-CE093F11xxxx}"&#gt;
        &#lt;SilverlightMobileCSProjectFlavor&#gt;

          &#lt;FullDeploy &#gt; True  &#lt;/FullDeploy&#gt;

        &#lt;/SilverlightMobileCSProjectFlavor&#gt;
      &#lt;/FlavorProperties&#gt;
    &#lt;/VisualStudio&#gt;
  &#lt;/ProjectExtensions&#gt;
&#lt;/Project&#gt;
```

This is the vanila csproj file of my Wp7 App. There is no SupportCulture tags in it. So, I have to add this tag in it right when I open it with notepad? When I downloaded your sample app, I open the csproj file with notepad, i dont see this tag either?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a blog on this very subject just the other day.  It describes how to localize from start to finish, and it is located at www.hopnet.mobi, click Blogs.

Once you get the hang of it, localization really isn't difficult at all.  I've localized one app, and I'm waiting on a friend to validate my translations.  While she's doing that, I'm localizing the other apps.  More languages means wider distribution, which means more money.  You're doing the right thing!

Comment: This is a very very good article on this subject. I have these questions; 1) open .csproj file in note.  I dont see the tags as in your articles. The last inner tag is :SilverlightMobileCSProjectFlavor tag.  from here I add the SupportedCultures tag and add the language codes?  2) Do I need to add other tags like XapOutputs and silverlightapplication tags ?? 3) when I open your .csproj I dont see the tags as you added. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the <SupportedCultures>en-US;es-ES;</SupportedCultures> tags?  In the vanilla csproj file, the tags are going to look like this:
<SupportedCultures>
</SupportedCultures> 

These tags will be about halfway down the file.  You add the supported cultures.  en-US;es-ES;it-IT;fr-FR;de-DE;en-GB; and so on - whichever languages you want to add.

Those are the only things you need to add to the .csproj file.  You're not adding tags, but adding items within the <SupportedCultures></SupportedCultures> tags.  Does this answser your question?

Comment: Thank you. I have copied the vanila csproj as above. I dont see the supportedCcultures Tag in it when I open it with notepad. Is that means we have to add it? This is just to show you what I have discovered. Thanks

Comment: Hi, How do handle the messageBox.show() for more than one langauges? Assuming all required resources files are added. Where to detect the phone's language so that the messageBox.Show() will use the right resource file?? thanks

Comment: For the messagebox.show (or any text displayed from code), you'd use the same method as is used in the ApplicationBar portion of the blog.  In fact, right below the ApplicationBar portion of the code are the methods that are the click events for the ApplicationBar, and there are MessageBox.Show examples there.  No need to do more work to detect the phone's language.  The app detects it once, when it first launches.

Comment: Out of luck. It does not work! I followed your steps exactly except no applicationbar. 1) I opened the csproj file and ADD the tag maually. 2) Followed all your steps in App xaml and App.xaml.cs 3) build the solution. What seems to be the problems?

Comment: I believe your csproj file is from the mango version. I think the problem is in Xaml : localized  and local for the class to access the resources file. any diff on localized and local ?  It seems "local" seems to work.

Comment: If you're referring to the blog entry code, my project was written using NoDo, not Mango.  I just started my first Mango project yesterday.

Show me code.

Comment: I figured out the problem.  The "csproj" file that you have pasted code for above is NOT the .csproj file.  It is the .csproj.USER file (emphasis added).  Look in the directory, right above that file, and you should see the .csproj file, without the .user extension.

Comment: OMG, YES, YES, U are right. It is the project file itself. I was wrong to use csproj user file. Funny thing is it works too! Wonder why Chinese (zh-CN,zh-TW) not working? my chinese file foramt is AppResources.zh-CN.resx, I add this style: zh;es  or zh-CN;es-ES in SupportedCultures and both are not working. why? any clue? Thank u very much.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your question...  If you want Chinese and Spanish, you'd go with zh-CN;es-ES; in the supported languages tag.  Assuming zh-TW is correct for Taiwan (I didn't look it up), you could add that one as well.  But for EACH language, you need another resource file.  If you put zh-TW and es-ES in the csproj file, you need to add a .zh-TW.resx and a .es-ES.resx to the resources.

Comment: Thanks. It is working now for Chinese(zh-CN). I really appreciate your help. Looking forward to read your new articles soon.

Answer (score 3):

The way you're trying to do localization is to get very complicated, have lots of duplication and be difficult to change in the future.

There is a built in way of supporting multiple languages/cultures/etc. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637522(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Agreed.  I18n is a potential minefield if you try to do it piecemeal like in the original question.  Lots of thought and attention has been given to the problem, and the linked article is probably the best place to start to prevent rolling your own (probably flawed) implementation.

Comment: Thank. I will visit the link. My intention is that I use a single textBlock to display the SAME message for the languages supported. This will save space. This way I need to produce one app for 3 or more languages. Would appreciate if you can show me a way to follow and to understand your recommended way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I begin to see your point on difficulty to edit and get complicated. I still dont know how to set up a globalized app. Thanks for this hard truth about my method above.

Answer (score 0):

Use CurrentCulture which is in your System.Globalization namespace. It has properties like Name, EnglishName, DisplayName and NativeName so you pick which one suits you most.

EDIT: Detecting the language will depend on whether you want to allow users to change the language or not. If not then detect it in App.xaml.cs and store the information in an IsolatedStorage object so that you can share it among different pages. This way you can avoid detecting the language settings later and just rely on the saved settings. As for the best practice I stick to CultureInfo. I never tried going directly through Thread.CurrentThread.

Comment: Thanks. Would appreciate if you can help me with the above questions.

Comment: Thank. Will give it a go. BTW, what is the diff b/ween Globalized and localized app? If my app support more than 3 languages, it is globalized or localized app? Is localized app means supporting a specific language as well as English? Thanks

Comment: Globalization is a unique name for culture specific information like number and date format, calendars, currency format, etc. What you are interested in are internationalization and localization. The first one is adapting your software for a particular language, eg. english, spanish, portugese. The latter one is about localizing particular international version. For example, you have Spanish language, but you then localize your app for market in Spain, Mexico, Peru, Chile, etc.